# Jenkins to run Jmeter script

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins

Question is how to run a jmeter script using jenkins job.
Is there any pre-requisites like standard variable names and all.

I have heard that there are different plugins, some can just execute the script as it is while some other can take inputs from gui as well as provides  report as chart or graph.

Also some posts says first we need to create ant programs and then need to call them from jenkins.

If possible, please detail  the exact procedure and suitable plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following two methods:

1. You can run Jmeter in non-GUI mode using command line ("Execute Windows batch command" or "Execute Shell" build step in Jenkins job settings)

> jmeter.bat -n -t path_to_your_jmx_script.jmx

Of course, you can do the same by launching Jmeter as a java application or within shell script.

2. By "Invoke Ant" build step.
   This method provides you all the benefits of ant. So, just include jmeter in appropriate ant target in your build.xml file. Here is an example (jvmarg and jmeterarg are not required):

   ```
   <target name="test" depends="clean">
        <jmeter jmeterhome="${jmeter-home}"resultlogdir="results/jtl">
             <testplans dir="scripts" includes="*.jmx"></testplans>
             <jmeterarg value="-Jbackend=${env.Backend_Address}"/>
             <jvmarg value="-Xmx512m"/>    
             <jvmarg value="-Xdebug"/>
        </jmeter>
   </target>
   ```

And that's how you can generate nice report:

```
<target name="report" depends="test">
     <xslt classpathref="xslt.classpath"
           basedir="results/jtl"
           destdir="results/html"
           includes="*.jtl"
           style="${jmeter-home}/extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl">
           <param name="showData" expression="${show-data}"/>
    </xslt>    
    <copy file="${jmeter-home}/extras/expand.png" tofile="results/html/expand.png"></copy>
    <copy file="${jmeter-home}/extras/collapse.png" tofile="results/html/collapse.png"></copy>
</target>
```

Regarding Jenkins plugins - the only one I know (and use) is Performance Plugin that can mark your build as failed/passed based on Jmeter results and generate nice graphs.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i need a jenkins plugin that can execute jmeter script. So please share the details of the plugin you mentioned. Anyway thanks for ant script, i will look into that.

Comment: Ant do run the jmeter script based on build.xml file with appropriate targets I mentioned above. Jenkins plugin (Performance Plugin) just process result files generated by Jmeter, doesn't matter how they were generated. Actually, it's not really important how to launch Jmeter as any method (even the simplest) is OK, all you need is just to pass required parameters that can be easily done with CLI. Interpretation of Jmeter results is much more difficult. That's the place where plugins should be used, not for launching.

Answer (score 1):

This site has the detailed information on Jmeter + Ant + Jenkins integration.
Other than running the test, you might also be interested in generating reports, charts and mailing the results.

Check here:

http://www.testautomationguru.com/jmeter-continuous-performance-testing-part2/

Comment: Is there any possibility of running jmeter and getting results without using ants.Means directly using some jmeter plugin?

Comment: you can use jenkins performance plugin to parse the jmeter result file. You do not need Ant.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins doesn't provide any plugins to execute a JMeter test, it is up to you how you will launch it, the choices are in:

- [Command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- [Ant task](http://www.programmerplanet.org/projects/jmeter-ant-task/)
- [Maven plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin)

So you need to add a build step which will trigger JMeter test execution using one of above approaches. Also you can add [Performance Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Performance+Plugin) as a post-build action in order to be able to visualise performance trends and set pass and fail criteria.

See [Continuous Integration 101: How to Run JMeter With Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/continuous-integration-101-how-run-jmeter-jenkins) article for detailed walkthrough.

Comment: Jenkins Performance Plugin is abandoned at the moment, it needs a new maintainer. I've been tryign to use it, with no luck. It's buggy, bugs are well known and already tracked in its issue tracker and no one seems to be working on it. I'd strongly recommend to stay away from this plugin, before you run into issues which will impact your delivery.